# Spring MVC - How to post to any URL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to post `http://localhost:8080/TestSpringMVCAndStuff/hi/zzz?input=abcdef&crap=1234567` to a `/hi/*` address.

However, I keep getting 404 error.

Is there a way to make this work?

WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        {
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                    "dispatcherHi", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            servlet.addMapping("/hi/*");
        }
    }
}
```

AnotherController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hi/*")
public class AnotherController {
    @Autowired(required=false)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        try{
            response.getOutputStream().write("hello world!".getBytes());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

WebAppConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.springmvc")
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * Configure View Resolver 
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /*
     * Configure MessageSource to provide internationalized messages
     * 
     */

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    /*
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `addMapping("/hi/*")` or `addMapping("/*")`.

Comment: Remove `@Autowired(required=false)`. The processing method is not an Bean initialization method.

Comment: Why use `getOutputStream()` if you're going to write text? Use `response.getWriter().write("hello world!");`. And don't ignore exceptions. Just add `throws IOException` to the method. Spring will handle it.

Comment: Made the 3 changes... POST still returns 404.

Comment: I have included the Configuration in case it matters.

Comment: You didn't change `addMapping()`.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it in the code, but neglected to update it here. Please take a look again. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In this Context Initializer servlet mapping is **/hi/*** so each and every request to the server will be like http://localhost:8080/TestSpringMVCAndStuff/hi

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebAppConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);
    {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcherHi", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/hi/*");
    }
 }
}
```

so that there is no need of **@RequestMapping("/hi/*")** this because **/hi** is already appended in context path so after **hi/** only need a request Mapping @RequestMapping( value="/zzz")

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/**")
 public class AnotherController { 

 @RequestMapping(value="/zzz",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String result="";
    try{
       result="hello world";
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
 }
```

inCase he change servlet Mapping like this means **servlet.addMapping("/")**   he should Map Request for **/hi** in Controller and futher request also

Comment: Hello, I am trying to post to `/hi/**`. The other URLs are supposed to be used for other stuff.

Comment: Yah! your correct  its possible to make more than  method for other stuff like bellow   @RequestMapping(value="/zzz",method = RequestMethod.GET) or @RequestMapping(value="/zzz",method = RequestMethod.PUT) or @RequestMapping(value="/zzz",method = RequestMethod.DELETE)

Comment: Why do you think it will be useful? What does `/**"` accomplish? Why do you think so?

Comment: Yes! @SotiriosDelimanolis his mapping is  like addMapping("/hi/*") so his request ill be   /hi/**  always so  i added /** in controller and method  /zzz

Comment: Please rephrase that, I did not understand. Also, show us proof from the Spring MVC's documentation that what you're suggesting will work.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis i have updated my answer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html and my demo project like for you https://github.com/kalai6095/springcrud

Comment: While I understand your solution would surely work by making it POST the `/zzz` as a value instead of part of the URI, the idea behind this test project is to use Spring to support URL with accompanying .jsp files for some, as well as URL with no accompanying .jsp files.